# The Weblogic server shuts down on closing the script window?

Tags: dns, weblogic, middleware, fusion

I have installed the Fusion SOA 11.1.1.5 on a remote linux (64 bit) machine and successfully started the weblogic server by using the startWeblogic.sh command from the DOMAIN_HOME/ folder (not from the DOMAIN_HOME/bin/ folder). I have a couple of doubts wrt this:

1. Is this the correct startWeblogic.sh script that should be executed, i.e. the one in the domain_home or the one in the domain_home/bin ?
2. I could get the server up by just running the startWeblogic.sh from the domain_home folder, but on closing the window running the script the server alos goes down. What is the correct way to start the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Is this the correct startWeblogic.sh script that should be executed,
>   i.e. the one in the domain_home or the one in the domain_home/bin ?

Yes - the startWeblogic.sh in DOMAIN_HOME is the right one to run, it internally will call the bin/startWeblogic.sh. Just check it out by reading the file in the DOMAIN_HOME

> 2.I could get the server up by just running the startWeblogic.sh from
>   the domain_home folder, but on closing the window running the script
>   the server alos goes down. What is the correct way to start the server
>   ?

SO you are running the Weblogic sh in the foreground, which is why it temrinates when you close the window. You can send this to background by doing

```
command  &
```

i.e.

```
startWeblogic.sh &
```

see more at http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/startdoc/shell.html#run

Later you can recover the running processes and bring it back into foreground, but I guess you only need to tail the running logs to see what's happening within Weblogic.